# VBA - replace Autofilter with two dictionaries

Tags: vba, dictionary, replace

I am trying to replace Autofilter with two dicionaries, but is it doesn't work the way I am expecting.

I was thinking that way - the data from table 1 will be in dict and dictF will be the small another table where I want to look for.

It should simultaneously check all the conditions in dictF for each element of dict.

If element from dict is not in dictF then this element should be removed.

So pseudocode decription would be:

For each item in dict check simultaneously all elements of dictF and if item from dict is one of those dictF elements then leave it in dict, otherwise remove item from dict.

Simultaneosly is crucial here - there may be even like 20 keys in dictf that should be checked at one step.

My code for this routine to remove

```
For Each a In dict.Keys()

     For Each b In dictF.Keys()

        If NOT dict.Exists(b) Then
            c = 0

        Else
            c = 1

        End If

    If c = 0 Then dict.Remove a

    Next b


Next a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps as follows

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckDicts()
    'If element from dict is not in dictF then this element should be removed.
    Dim dict As Object, dictF As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictF = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dict.Add "a", 1
    dict.Add "b", 2
    dict.Add "c", 2

    dictF.Add "a", 1
    dictF.Add "b", 2
    dictF.Add "d", 2

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict
        If Not dictF.Exists(key) Then dict.Remove key
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @ssanguszko Please read QHarr's comment. It helps other people with the same question as well as those who help by writing answers when "the answer" is indicated.